# How can we set user profile photos in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, users, photo

The initial log-in screen shows at least one user which can be logged into the system, with a blank photo. How can we add or change this user-image?  The manual shows nothing relevant when searched for 'image', 'photo', etc.

Possibly related: [[Ubuntu 20.04] Change your login screen photo](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-changepicture.html) and [Where is 'Users and User groups' in Lubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230071/where-is-users-and-user-groups-in-lubuntu-20-04) and [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: System Settings --> Account Details --> User Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubuntu 20.04 uses `sddm` as its default display manager.

What you've described is the default "face" located in `/usr/share/sddm/faces`:

[image: default face in log-in screen]

The easiest way is to have an image called exactly `.face.icon` in each user's home folder.

Here, I've copied over `/usr/share/icons/oxygen/base/64x64/emotes/face-angel.png` to my home folder as `.face.icon`.

[image: different face]